# Multiselect Spinner with hints

Tags: java, android

hey i want add hint to MultiSelector from [https://github.com/wongk/MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/wongk/MultiSelectSpinner/blob/master/src/com/multiselectspinner/widget/MultiSelectSpinner.java)
i mixed it with [https://github.com/ravivyas84/AndroidSpinnerHint](https://github.com/ravivyas84/AndroidSpinnerHint/blob/master/src/com/ravivyas/spinnerHint/landing.java)

its look like this i add own `SpinnerAdapterProxy` that extends `ArrayAdapter<String>`

```
public MultiSelectSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);

    _proxyAdapter = new SpinnerAdapterProxy(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    super.setAdapter(_proxyAdapter);
    _context = context;
}
(...)

public void setHint(String hint) {
    _proxyAdapter.setHint(hint);
}
```

adapter

```
public class SpinnerAdapterProxy extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private LayoutInflater mInflator;
private TextView text;
private boolean selected = false;
private String hint;

public SpinnerAdapterProxy(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mInflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflator.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        if (!selected) {
                text.setHint(hint);
        } else {
                text.setHint(this.getItem(position));
        }
        return convertView;
}

public void setHint(String hint) {

    this.hint = hint;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}
}
```

and place where i create `MultiSelectSpinner` and `setTitle`

```
province = (MultiSelectSpinner) findViewById(R.id.subregion);
province.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.choose_province));
province.setItems(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.provinces));
```

the problem is that after `setHint` adapter did not refresh and did not show hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just fixed by myself

i throw out `SpinnerAdapterProxy` and just modify `MultiSelectSpinner`
by change

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
    if (_selection != null) {
        String select = null;
        if (which < _selection.length) _selection[which] = isChecked;

        if (!isAnySelect()) 
            select = _title;
        else 
            select = buildSelectedItemString();

        _proxyAdapter.clear();
        _proxyAdapter.add(select);
        setSelection(0);
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
    }
}
```

and

```
public void setTitle(String title) {
    _title = title;
    _proxyAdapter.clear();
    _proxyAdapter.add(title);
    setSelection(0);
}
```

and added testing finction that test if any item is selected

```
private boolean isAnySelect() {
    for (boolean b : _selection) {
        if (b == true) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @mar do u have any idea how to remove toast message once u select items?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar sorry but i dont know what you talking about? what toast? even in code i paste in here theres no toast

Comment: @Mariusz i am not sure but when i select options and press back button, there appears to be a small toast message with all list of strings. yes there is no Toast everywhere but i am unable to explain this behaviour. By clicking anywhere on screen it disappears

Comment: sorry cant help you, when dialog with options is on top and i press back button nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

If you use following class you can add hint as following methord

```
public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner implements
DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {

    String _title;
    String[] _items = null;
    boolean[] mSelection = null;

    ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;

    List<KotItems> mKotdata;
    int pos;

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                                                  R.layout.spinneritemstyle);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                                                  R.layout.spinneritemstyle);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[which] = isChecked;

            simple_adapter.clear();
            simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
        } else {
            simple_adapter.add("N/A");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                               "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {

                mKotdata.get(pos).setKotnote(buildSelectedItemString());

            }
        });



        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                                   "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
    }

    //Add Your Hint in this methord
    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        if(items.size()>0){
            _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
            mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
            simple_adapter.clear();
            simple_adapter.add("Add Your Hint Here");
            Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
        }


    }


    public void setArrayList(List<KotItems> mKotdata,int pos){

        this.mKotdata = mKotdata;
        this.pos = pos;

    }


    public void setSelection(int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
        }
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                                               + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }



    private String buildSelectedItemString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;

                sb.append(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("u8u8 "+sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }




}
```